# why do two mysql lock and flush statements on different dbs hang

Tags: mysql

Consider we have two identical dbs a and b.

First i connect to db a with the client

mysql -ua -pa a

I issue the commands

```
lock tables table1 write, table2 write; 
flush tables table1, table2;
```

without closing the session i open a new session

mysql -ub -pb b

I issue the same commands

```
lock tables table1 write, table2 write; 
flush tables table1, table2;
```

The second flush looks to be stuck.
Only when i close the first connection, the second flush has success.

Why does this happen. These are two different dbs?
How can i avoid this from happening?

I use mysql 5.1 and all tables are myisam tables.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a defect in mysql 5.1, which does not appear anymore in mysql 5.5